# getting 415 error while posting in requests in rest api , trying to run cms query

Tags: python-3.x, restful-authentication, business-objects

Hi I am new to python and REST API,

I am getting 415 error while trying to run a query in cms using `requests.post`

I am not able to pass `content-type` and `Accept` along with the logon token.
I am able to run this in talend along with these 2 headers.

Can you please help me in how to add these 2 headers in requests.post at the end.

Below is my code

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as x
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xmltodict
protocol='http'
host='HOST'
port='6405'
content_type='application/xml'
base_url = protocol + '://' + host + ':' + port
bip_url = base_url + '/biprws'
webi_url = bip_url + '/raylight/v1'
sl_url = bip_url + '/sl/v1'
headers_auth = {
        'Content-Type' : content_type,'Accept':'application/xml'
        }
headers = {
    }      
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
auth = requests.get(bip_url + '/logon/long', headers=headers)
root = etree.fromstring(auth.text)
root[3].text = username
root[0].text = password 
etree.tostring(root)
send = requests.post(bip_url + '/logon/long',
        headers=headers_auth,
        data=etree.tostring(root))
tokenresp = etree.fromstring(send.content)
headers['X-SAP-LogonToken'] = tokenresp[3][0][0].text
folder_get = requests.get(bip_url + '/v1/cmsquery', headers=headers)
folder_root = etree.fromstring(folder_get.text)
Query_var = 'SELECT SI_ID,SI_NAME FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE SI_ANCESTOR = 12141'
folder_root[0].text = Query_var
data1 = etree.tostring(folder_root)
folder_post = requests.post(bip_url + '/v1/cmsquery', headers = headers, data = data1)
folder_post.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 415 means that you're passing a content type that the API doesn't accept.  You need to configure your headers correctly.  Try this:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/xml'
}
auth = requests.get(bip_url + 'logon/long', headers=headers)
print(auth.status_code)
```

It looks like your problem is that you set headers to a blank dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked with your suggestion. Thanks again

Comment: @ManishKothari You can accept this answer.